# PouchDB: Clear localDB when it is safe on remoteDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

**Context**

I use PouchDB and have a localDB using indexedDb. I continuously replicating this local DB to a remote DB (CouchDB) with this function:

```
function replLocalToRemote() {
    this.meta.localDB.replicate.to(this.meta.remoteDB, {
      // Live: replication occurs as the changes are detected
    live: true,
    retry: true,
    }).on('paused', function (info) {
      console.log('paused', info);
      // replication was paused, usually because of a lost connection
    }).on('change', function (change) {
      console.log('change', change);
      // yo, something changed!
    }).on('active', function (info) {
      console.log('active', info);
      // replication was resumed
    }).on('error', function (err) {
      alert('replication failed. Retry... ', err);
      // totally unhandled error (shouldn't happen)
    });
  }
```

It is working well but problems appear when there is too much data on the device. Especially on IOS where Safari constantly open pop-up windows to ask for more data storage (beginning at 5Mo).

**Question**

So I would like to clean the localDB as I replicate it to the remoteDB. For instance delete a document on local as soon as it is on remote and continue replication even if there is more data on remote than on local.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you might be able to avoid the pop-ups and the storage shortage problem by using a SQLite database instead of IndexedDB and WebSQL. See the _SQLite plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap_ section [here](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html).

Comment: @Phonolog Interesting but my app is not a Cordova/PhoneGap app.

Comment: Hmm another idea: Delete your database once there's too much data in it (or let's say every day/week/month) and create a new one. Replicate the new one to your remote db...

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the local document would cause you problems, as the deletion would be replicated to the remote database so that you lose the document altogether.

Have you seen the "auto-compaction" feature in PouchDb? That minimises the size of the local database by removing any "non-leaf" revision documents (previous versions).

You can enable this feature like this:

```
var db = new PouchDB('mydb', {auto_compaction: true});
```

More information about this is on [the PouchDb page](https://pouchdb.com/guides/compact-and-destroy.html#auto-compaction).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the database size is not due to revisions but to different documents. So the compaction would not really decrease the size.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is create a new local db every now and then (e.g. every day), and starting a new replication from there. Keep the old dbs as long as they still replicate, and remove them as soon as they are fully replicated.

In order not to lose any data, you should take extra care that all data has been replicated to the server before deleting the db.

Comment: The problem is that I'll need to replicate to a new remote db each time I create a new local one. The remote db structure will be then hard to keep clean.

Comment: Not exactly. You can replicate to the same remote database easily. If you can elaborate on your special use case, I can help you more.